# trouble with creating a project for Pymakr in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, esp32, micropython, arduino-esp32

hey i want to start programming an Arduino esp32 board with micropython so i installed pymakr extension on vscod but then when i wanted to create a project i see this error:

> Error running command pymakr.createProjectPrompt: command 'pymakr.createProjectPrompt' not found. This is likely caused by the extension that contributes pymakr.createProjectPrompt.
> [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urx6Y.png)

i uninstall and install the extension again but it heppened again i also tried opening a workspace and it didnt help either.
id be thankfull if you tell me whats wrong and how can i solve it.